# Out-File: why should I combine -Append and -NoClobber? Isn't -Append enough?

Tags: powershell

I fail to see the difference between

```
... | Out-File -Append
```

and

```
... | Out-File -Append -NoClobber
```

Both append information to the file, both don't overwrite the contents, both create the file if it doesn't exist. And yet, all the examples on the internet use the combination of `-Append` and `-NoClobber`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: NoClobber means don't over-write the file.

Comment: But so does `append`, no?

Comment: But my question is: why use `-Append -NoCLobber`? Why  not just `-Append`?

_NoClobber 
Will not overwrite (replace the contents) of an existing file. By default, if a file exists in the specified path, Out-File overwrites the file without warning. If **both Append and NoClobber are used**, the output is appended to the existing file._

Even the help doesn't make sense to me.  Why would I need to use both Append and NoClobber?  Append - by design - won't overwrite the file, right?

Comment: You don't. See "jon Z"'s answer below. `NoClobber` is used to make sure that you only save the output if no file already exists. If one exists, it fails. `Append` adds to the end of a file(or creates one if the file didn't exist). You "never" use them together. They are for 2 different scenarios

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`-NoClobber` will set the FileMode (how the operating system should open a file) to CreateNew (= if the file already exists, an IOException exception is thrown), *unless* `-Append` has been specified in which case it will set the FileMode to Append (= opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or creates a new file).

So, for all practical purposes, `-Append -NoClobber` = `-Append`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It confirms what I suspected.  I still don't quite understand why, even in the official help documentation, they use the combination of both - but at least I can now be at ease when using `-Append` without `-NoClobber`.

Answer (score 0):

- -Append   (search for the end of the file and add new contents)
- -NoClobber    (throw a warning if the file is already exist)

Please read more on [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-File?view=powershell-5.0)